# SSRS Expressions - Aggregate "Group by" notworking

Tags: reporting-services

I have a dataset with a bunch of sales data (Dataset name is Summary), which I have got in a report and I have rolled up by month in a matrix. I also have to add 3/6/12 month averages, whereby each month is summed and then divided by the number of months in the average.

My original expression to just average everything worked fine, as below

> =Avg(IIF(Fields!ByDate.Value >= DateAdd("d", - ((Day(today) - 1)), DateAdd("m", - 3, Today)), Fields!SoldValue.Value, Nothing))

However, when adding the Scope variable to group by each month, this failed

> =Avg(IIF(Fields!ByDate.Value >= DateAdd("d", - ((Day(today) - 1)), DateAdd("m", - 3, Today)), Fields!SoldValue.Value, Nothing),Fields!GroupBy.Value)

What I want is for it to Sum each month and then do the average. I tried to add the sum in, but that didn't work.

> =Avg(SUM(IIF(Fields!ByDate.Value >= DateAdd("d", - ((Day(today) - 1)), DateAdd("m", - 3, Today)), Fields!SoldValue.Value, Nothing)),Fields!GroupBy.Value)

Is anyone able to point me in the direction of how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

The Scope must be a string. A field or parameter cannot be used for the scope of an aggregate.

> The  expression for the  '' has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate
> function. The scope parameter **must be set to a string constant** that is
> equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a
> containing data region, or the name of a dataset.

[MS Docs: Invalid Scope](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/expression-scope-for-totals-aggregates-and-built-in-collections?view=sql-server-ver16)

I'm not sure what you're trying to use three different datasets for the 3/6/12 month average datasets. Can't you just make the months a variable in `DateAdd("M", - 3, Today))`? Also, the lower case M in your expression is for minutes ([Format Strings - MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings?redirectedfrom=MSDN)).

But you could use a SWITCH statement and choose the corresponding expression. Maybe something like

```
=SWITCH(
Fields!GroupBy.Value = "MONTH3", Avg(IIF(Fields!ByDate.Value >= DateAdd("d", - ((Day(today) - 1)), DateAdd("m", - 3, Today)), Fields!SoldValue.Value, Nothing),"MONTH3")
,Fields!GroupBy.Value = "MONTH6", Avg(IIF(Fields!ByDate.Value >= DateAdd("d", - ((Day(today) - 1)), DateAdd("m", - 6, Today)), Fields!SoldValue.Value, Nothing),"MONTH6"),
Fields!GroupBy.Value = "MONTH12", Avg(IIF(Fields!ByDate.Value >= DateAdd("d", - ((Day(today) - 1)), DateAdd("m", - 12, Today)), Fields!SoldValue.Value, Nothing),"MONTH12")
)
```